# Bernoulli Differential Equation solving

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello I have the equation $$x'=-tx+e^{-t^2/4}{x^{1/2}}$$ I made the Bernoulli-Substitution $$u=x^{1/2}$$ and got the equation $$u'=-1/2tu+1/2e^{t^{2}/4}$$
Now I dont know how to solve this equation. Thanks Ciwan

Comment: The equation is now exact, you just need to find an integrating factor and multiply through by it.

Comment: what do you mean with integrating factor?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor#Solving_first_order_linear_ordinary_differential_equations) Wiki link

Answer (score 1):

Write your equation in the form
$$\frac{x'(t)}{2\sqrt{x(t)}}+\frac{1}{2}t\sqrt{x(t)}$$
substituting $$v(t)=\sqrt{x(t)}$$ and computing an integrating factor $$\mu(t)=e^{\int\frac{t}{2}dt}=e^{t^2/4}$$ so we get
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{t^2/4}v(t)\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$